# Load Texture From File problem Android NDK and OpenGL

Tags: android, c++, graphics, opengl-es

I am trying to load an image through OpenGL and stbi_load on android ndk. The problem is that it is generating an invalid texture (equal to zero).

```
LoadTextureFromFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/BPV/mic_close.jpg", &amp;amp;amp;my_image_texture, &amp;amp;amp;my_image_width, &amp;amp;amp;my_image_height);

bool CGUI::LoadTextureFromFile(const char* filename, GLuint* out_texture, int* out_width, int* out_height)
{
    // Load from file
    int image_width = 0;
    int image_height = 0;
    unsigned char* image_data = stbi_load(filename, &amp;amp;image_width, &amp;amp;image_height, NULL, 4);
    if (image_data == NULL)
        return false;

    // Create a OpenGL texture identifier
    GLuint image_texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &amp;amp;image_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image_texture);

    // Setup filtering parameters for display
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Upload pixels into texture
    glPixelStorei(0x0CF2, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
    stbi_image_free(image_data);

    *out_texture = image_texture; // Receive zero
    *out_width = image_width;
    *out_height = image_height;
    return true;
}
```

I use libGLESv2

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
  GLuint image_texture;
  glGenTextures(1, &image_texture);
  ...
  *out_texture = image_texture; // Receive zero
```

`glGenTextures()` just allocates new object and practically never fails, save when called without active OpenGL context.

On Android platform, OpenGL rendering is usually done in dedicated working thread (different from GUI thread), so most likely you call the method from the wrong thread or before OpenGL context initialization (which cannot be deduced from the given code sample).

Comment: You are probably correct. I didn't start OpenGL and I don't even know how to do it in a simple and effective way. I am developing a "mod", so how should I implement the OpenGL context boot? I have two main functions that I think would be appropriate for this: void InitInGame () and void MainLoop ()

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot suggest where to start - it depends on the game architecture (I suppose that modified game already uses OpenGL ES, otherwise it makes no sense to me loading any textures; but apart from that, it is unclear how texture could be used without knowing game rendering pipeline details).